Publishing google play application in private mode
Here is my case:
I have been developing an application and I would like to distribute it using google play console. 
I would like to distribute it so only the members of a third company can download it from store. Is it a way to make it visible on market just for the google accounts I specify or something similar? 
I've been looking for answers and I found this I don't know if this really fits my case. From here I understand that this third company should be the one creating the organization and distribute my application for their organization, am I right? 

Yes you are right.

You can host Android apps specifically for your organization in the managed Google Play store

They should create the account and give you access to submit your private app

If you aren't the one who publishes private apps, you can allow other users or third-party developers to publish private apps.

